# show artist image on lock screen

Tags: zune, music, lock-screen

i did read a lot of posts regarding this issue, but i m still to figure out a way to get this working.
I have the Nokia Lumia 720, and i have enabled the show artist image on lock screen while playing music, but everytime i lock my screen the default image from the album is shown even when i m playing music.

most of the posts mentions connecting to ztunes and all, but isnt it that the WP8 phones doesnt need ztunes now to sync?

sorry for the repeated question, but i really cant find a way out :(

**UPDATE**

I found out that if i play music from Music+Videos app rather than from Nokia Music, the wall paper turns to grey when i lock the screen.

Comment: Do you mean sync with Zune?

Comment: Hmm, works for me on my Lumia 920. Have you tried playing a song sample from the store and locking your phone, does it change?

Comment: yes i did, but it still doesnt show

Answer (score 3):

Not all artists have artist wallpaper available, so for some artists you may get album art, or a coloured background.

Answer (score 0):

The phone will only display a single image for each artist if it finds a match in the xbox music cloud.

You can manually add images or change them using MPA Tool.  Search the store for MPA Tool you should find it.

You cant sync the phone with Zune but there are alternative methods. This is the desktop version for Windows: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop but there are Windows 8 and Apple versions.

Comment: Does the Zune Music (or Xbox Music) service needs to be available in your country?